# is there any powershell command to count the number of ids in a line on log file?

Tags: windows, powershell, command

is there any powershell command to count the number of ids in a line on log file?
for example imagine this a line in log file -

> 2021-04-27 15:12:04.5797  INFO Generated Call Log IDs: 4219860,4219861,4219862,4219863,4219864,4219865,4219866,4219867,4219868,4219869,4219870,4219871,4219872,4219873,4219874,4219875,4219876,4219877,4219878,4219879,4219880,4219881,4219882,4219883.

I have to check the number of event log ids generated in the log for the particular log completion time in this case it is 15:12:04 cst.

Comment: If the line is in the format you suggest and is stored in the variable `$line`, then this will get the number of IDs: `($line.split(':')[-1].Split(',') | Measure-Object).Count`

Answer (score 1):

```
$line ="2021-04-27 15:12:04.5797 INFO Generated Call Log IDs: 4219860,4219861,4219862,4219863,4219864,4219865,4219866,4219867,4219868,4219869,4219870,4219871,4219872,4219873,4219874,4219875,4219876,4219877,4219878,4219879,4219880,4219881,4219882,4219883."

(($line -split "IDs: ")[1] -split ","  | Measure-Object).Count
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# data simulating log
$log = @'
2021-04-27 15:12:04.5797 INFO Generated Call Log IDs: 4219860,4219861,4219862,4219863,4219864,4219865,4219866,4219867,4219868,4219869,4219870,4219871,4219872,4219873,4219874,4219875,4219876,4219877,4219878,4219879,4219880,4219881,4219882,4219883.
2021-04-27 15:15:04.5797 INFO Generated Call Log IDs: 4219860,4219861,4219862,4219863,4219864,4219865,4219866,4219867,4219868,4219869,4219870,4219871,4219872.
'@ -split '\r?\n'

$log | ForEach-Object {
    # Regex with named capturing groups to get date and ids
    if ($_ -match '(?<date>^(?:\d+-?)+\s(?:\d+:?)+).*?IDs:\s?(?<ids>(?:\d+,?)+)\.?') {
        $ids = $Matches.ids -split ','

        # Create output objects with date, ids, and id count
        [pscustomobject]@{date = [datetime]::parse($Matches.date); count = $ids.Count; ids = $ids }        }
}
```

Output

```
date                count ids
----                ----- ---
2021-04-27 15:12:04    24 {4219860, 4219861, 4219862, 4219863…}
2021-04-27 15:15:04    13 {4219860, 4219861, 4219862, 4219863…}
```

**Update**

Based off your repost of this question it seems like you want something a bit more focused.  Its sounds like you want to get count of IDs for a specific date/time string found in the log.

```
function Get-IdCountFromLog {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateScript( { Test-Path $_ })]
        [string]
        $Path,

        [Parameter()]
        [string]
        $DateStringPattern = '.*',

        # Use to return only count of IDs
        [Parameter()]
        [switch]
        $Count
    )

    Get-Content -Path $Path |
        Select-String -Pattern $DateStringPattern  |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line |
        ForEach-Object {
            # Regex with named capturing groups to get date and ids
            if ($_ -match '(?<date>^(?:\d+-?)+\s(?:\d+:?)+\.\d+).*?IDs:\s?(?<ids>(?:\d+,?)+)\.?') {
                $ids = $Matches.ids -split ','

                if ($Count.IsPresent) { $ids.Count }
                else {
                    # Create output objects with date, ids, and id count
                    [pscustomobject]@{date = $Matches.date; count = $ids.Count; ids = $ids }
                }
            }
        }
}

Get-IdCountFromLog -Path C:\temp\log.txt -DateStringPattern '2021-06-01 04:51:54.3094' -Count

8
```

Comment: Im geting error while executing as  **A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Raw'.**

Comment: @manojkumar, fixed.  I forgot `-Raw` is not available in powershell 5.1 and below.  I removed `-Raw` and changed to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line`